# capturing the data which is just about to get discarded from kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka topic's retention period is 7 days. But I need to push data which is expiring because of retention period to new kafka topic or some other storage.

So is there any method where I can access the data which is going to be deleted after 7 days just before it gets deleted? or way to set up some process where it will automatically push data which is going to get deleted to some place else.

Comment: No, it's not really possible to get any notifications about this, but lookup "Kafka tiered storage"

Answer (score 0):

Since 0.10 version of kafka each message has a timestamp. Simply setup a consumer group that starts every hour and processes each topic partition from the initial offset (auto.offset.reset=earliest) and pushes on the new topic the messages with the timestamp with incoming expiration (one hour width), then the consumer group stops and is restarted one hour later.